# How to stop Jquery function with infinite loop while it is currently running

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an function that is executing an infinite number of times. Its a pulsing animation with a central button. This is the code.

```
    $('#child').hide();
$('#child1').hide();
$('#child2').hide();
$('#child3').hide();
$('#child4').hide();
fadeItIn();

function fadeItIn(){

// Fade Ins
    $('#child4').fadeIn(175);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#child3').fadeIn(175);
    },175);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#child2').fadeIn(175);
    },350);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#child1').fadeIn(175);
    },525);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#child').fadeIn(175);
    },700); 



// Fade Outs
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#child').fadeOut(175);
    },875);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#child1').fadeOut(175);
    },1050);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#child2').fadeOut(175);
    },1225);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#child3').fadeOut(175);
    },1400);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#child4').fadeOut(175);
    },1575);


// Recall Function
    setTimeout(function(){
        fadeItIn();
    },5000);

};


// This function controlls the mouseover and mouseout events for the pulse


function bringForward(){
    $('#zoid1').css("z-index", "1");
    $('#zoid1').animate(
    { opacity: "1"}, 500, '');
};

function bringBack(){
    $('#zoid1').css("z-index", "-50");
    $('#zoid1').animate(
    { opacity: "0"}, 500, '');
};

$('#child5').mouseover(bringForward);
$('#zoid1').mouseout(bringBack);
```

What I want to do is when you click on a button somewhere else on the page, I want this function to stop and then later, when they click another button, I want the animation to start back up. How can I acheive this? I tried using the .stop command and it didnt work. The reason I need this to stop is because there are 16 of those animations on the page that all run at different times in groups of 4 and just hiding the DIV seems to screw up the timings.

I have made  a JS fiddle for the project. Thanks so much.

http://jsfiddle.net/VqWuv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag to control the loop

```
function ReStartAnimation() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!stopAnimation) fadeItIn();
        else ReStartAnimation()
    }, 5000);
}
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upBdw/)

Comment: You are my god. I will gladly skin elephants for you. But seriously thank you haha.

Answer (score 3):

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){
               fadeItIn();
            },5000);
```

and then to stop the timer: `clearTimeout(timer);`

Try it with the specifics of your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VqWuv/4/

I went ahead and added those things on a click function and this is what I got.